# pandas: more elegant way to retrieve row and set value if exists?

Tags: python, pandas

Using pandas, I find myself writing this a lot:

```
try:
    a = df.loc('A81001')
    a['somecol'] = 'someval'
except KeyError:
    pass
```

Is there a more elegant way to do things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's very elegant, but it will save you the `try`/`except`:

Consider the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(4), 'b': range(1, 5)})
df.b.values[df.a.values == 3] = 2
df.b.values[df.a.values == 30] = 3
>>> df
    a   b
0   0   1
1   1   2
2   2   3
3   3   2
```

So note that

```
df.b.values[df.a.values == 30] = 3
```

was a no-op.

---

Note that for the index, it's the same idea

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(4), 'b': range(1, 5)}).set_index('a')
df.b[df.index == 3] = 29
df.b[df.index == 30] = 3
```

Comment: Any idea how I'd do this for a dataframe that was indexed on `a`? I tried `df.b.values[df.idx == 30]` but got an error.